# Why Hive ParseDriver can not parse JoinClause sql like this?

Tags: java, sql, hive

Some simple queries can be parsed successfully! but the following can not.

The following sql can not be parsed:

```
FROM (SELECT p.datekey datekey, p.userid userid, c.clienttype  FROM detail.usersequence_client c JOIN fact.orderpayment p ON p.orderid = c.orderid  JOIN default.user du ON du.userid = p.userid WHERE p.datekey = 20131118 ) base  INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE `test`.`customer_kpi` SELECT base.datekey,   base.clienttype, count(distinct base.userid) buyer_count GROUP BY base.datekey, base.clienttype
```

code:

```
    public ASTNode getASTNode(String sql) throws IOException, ParseException {
        HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf();
        Configuration conf = new Configuration(hiveConf);
        Context context = new Context(conf);

        ParseDriver pd = new ParseDriver();
        ASTNode ast = pd.parse(sql, context);
        System.out.println(ast.dump());
        return ast;
   }
```

The error come out and I try to solved it with changing the version of depencies, but it does not work:

```
NoViableAltException(256@[])
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.atomjoinSource(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:2265)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.joinSource(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:2475)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.fromSource(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:1690)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.fromClause(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:1312)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.fromClause(HiveParser.java:42022)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.singleFromStatement(HiveParser.java:36335)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.fromStatement(HiveParser.java:36112)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpressionBody(HiveParser.java:35808)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:35710)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:2284)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1333)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:208)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
at com.oppo.logtrace.sql.parser.HiveQLParser.getASTNode(HiveQLParser.java:27)
at com.oppo.logtrace.utils.sql.parser.TestHiveQLParser.testGetASTNode(TestHiveQLParser.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:130)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 1:6 cannot recognize input near '(' 'SELECT' 'p' in joinSource
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)

pom:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

alibaba druid sql parser utils can help your with the sql.

```
   // first ,import maven dependency into your pom.xml 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

// test your sql ,it works fine 
@Test
public void testDruidSqlParser() throws ParseException {      
    String sql = "FROM (SELECT p.datekey datekey, p.userid userid, c.clienttype  FROM detail.usersequence_client c JOIN fact.orderpayment p ON p.orderid = c.orderid  JOIN default.user du ON du.userid = p.userid WHERE p.datekey = 20131118 ) base  INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE `test`.`customer_kpi` SELECT base.datekey,   base.clienttype, count(distinct base.userid) buyer_count GROUP BY base.datekey, base.clienttype";

    final SQLStatementParser hive = SQLParserUtils.createSQLStatementParser(sql, DbType.hive);
    final SQLStatement statement = hive.parseStatement();
    System.out.println(statement);
}
```

As you can see,it's kind of amazing.
[test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRri9.png)